# How would I login if I deleted all my logins?

Tags: discussion, support

I just recently looked at the login managmeent UI, and it seems to allow one to delete their last login method, while logged in. This seems dangerous.

How would one recover an account if they deleted their last OpenID login by accident?

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete your last login.

Comment: I tried and I was able to, unless StackExchange was not displaying all my logins. I immediately added it back before I was logged out though.